# Naming convention: how do you call the description of a value

Tags: naming-conventions

I'm building a form renderer, which can have a lot of different fields, selects, simple text inputs, checklists, etcetera.

Let's say one of these elements in our form is a list with a few items:

```
1(id) - Item A(description)
2 - Item B
3 - Item C
```

In my code I need to retrieve both the id and the description of the items in this list:

```
foreach ($this->fieldCollection->getFields() as $field) {

        $field->value = $this->getValue($field);
        $field->valueDescription = $this->getValueDescription($field);
}
```

What is a generally accepted name for the *description* of an item? As you can see I've gone for *valueDescription* in the example above, maybe *description* will just do, or maybe there is a better name for this.

Note that 'value' is not called 'id', this is because fields like normal text inputs or textareas also hold a value, which is generally a string of text, not an id.

Comment: First of all it seems strange to me that you use `value` for the ids... why not simply `id`?  
Apart from that, I see no reason to reiterate "value" in the name of the Description property. It would help to know what name have you given to these object, though, if you've given them a name at all.

Comment: Why not simply id? Good question! This is because the value might be something else than an id. I'm building a form renderer, and these objects correspond with fields in that form. Some elements would be a list, having id's as values, while some others might be a textarea or a simple input field, where 'id' would not suffice anymore.

Comment: I don't understand, you should explain more extensively what those objects are and what you are doing, in what language. Especially, do they have a named class? Or, say, they're just a bunch of unnamed objects in a json array? Just knowing that could make it a lot clearer. But a code dump would be a lot better. In any case, it's most likely that `description` is enough (vs `valueDescription`). Or that you're using the wrong (conceptually) structure.

Comment: I updated my question to clarify. Though I might just go ahead and agree with you that 'description' might be enough.

Comment: (1/2) Sorry, still not clear enough (for me). Anyway, what's wrong about `valueDescription` is that in an object-oriented language the properties/fields of an object should be indeed __attributes of that object__, not of some other thing. When you see a property/field for which the right name seems to be _ThingProperty_, in most cases you should make _Thing_ a separate object, and _Property_ a property/field of that object. (continues...)

Comment: ... (2/2) I haven't yet understood in your case what those objects are and what `value` means so I can't give you specific instructions, but it appears that you ought to have "value" objects with a `whateverThatValueAttributeActuallyIs` and `Description` as fields/properties. Whether these "value" objects ought to be the very object that you're asking about ("field"?) or objects contained in that object, I don't know.

Comment: BTW, use the "@user" functionality in your comments in the future when replying to someone, otherwise he won't get any notification (at the beginning of the comment type @ followed by the name of the user you're replying to)